# Excel to email with replace text in Premade Email Template

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the below code to auto-generate an email.

```
Public Function GenerateEmail(sendToText As String, _
    sendCCText As String, sendBCCText As String, _
    subjectText As String, fileName As String)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(fileName)

    With OutMail
        .sendTo = sendToText
        .CC = sendCCText
        .BCC = sendBCCText
        .Subject = subjectText
        .HTMLbody = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(OutMail.HTMLbody, "%TESTNUM%", "98541")
        .Attachments.Add (Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName)
        .Display
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Function
```

My end goal is to add data into the email and attach the active document into it as well. Everything here is working as intended, except the .HTLMbody section. It's giving me an error

> "Unable to get the Substitute property of the WorksheetFunction
>   class."

Am I missing a reference to a library? Should I be using something different?

The email is saved as .oft format, so I have a line in the email that has %TESTNUM% that I'm looking to replace with 98541 (or any other string I need to pass into the function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have HTML email working in Excel using very similar code.  The difference is that I build a temporary string with the text and you could do your substitute code on the string.
Then you can simply use:
.HTMLbody = temp_string

It might not be as elegant but it will help you work out where the problem is.